# Underflow in Forward-Backward Algorithms for HMM

Tags: python, algorithm, hidden-markov-models

I am learning about HMM and want to implement the Forward-Backward Algorithms(Baum Welch algorithm) in python. I use human genome from Human Genome Resources at NCBI as my input data. But it is too large that my alpha in Forward Algorithm and beta in Backward Algorithm will underflow (the number is too small to save). I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391625/underflow-in-forward-algorithm-for-hmms) with the same problem with me but its resource link is broken that I can't understand the answer. I also find [this](https://birc.au.dk/%7Ecstorm/courses/ML_e19/slides/ml-3-hmm-implementations.pdf) pdf, but I can't totally understand how to compute C_n and alpha^(zn) and how to implement it in python. Can anyone help me to solve the problem? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at [this](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/%7Erahimi/rabiner/rabiner-errata/rabiner-errata.html#forward_scaling) , It is hard to write the equations for C_t here. You should also consider using libraries that help you compute the Baum-Welch Algorithm such as [pomegranate](https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate) or [torchegranate](https://github.com/jmschrei/torchegranate)